# Detecting user's tap on notification

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

According to apple docs, we can identify user's tap on notification by checking whether the application state variable is inactive ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)).

> iOS Note: In iOS, you can determine whether an application is launched
>   as a result of the user tapping the action button or whether the
>   notification was delivered to the already-running application by
>   examining the application state. In the delegate’s implementation of
>   the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: or
>   application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method, get the value of the
>   applicationState property and evaluate it. If the value is
>   UIApplicationStateInactive, the user tapped the action button; if the
>   value is UIApplicationStateActive, the application was frontmost when
>   it received the notification.

But I can see a use case where there is a system alert (By system alert, I mean an alert view presented in the foreground of the app which is controlled by iOS) in foreground and the app is in inactive state (When a "system alert" is in view, the app behind is made inactive by iOS by setting app's [application state](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationState) to UIApplicationStateInactive) but the user will still be able to see the app's content on the screen. Refer the attachment below:

[image]

At this state if the app receives a notification, it will behave as though user tapped on notification. Is there a solution to solve this use case?

Comment: Quite confusing. What do u exactly mean by "system alert in foreground and the app is in inactive state"?

Comment: @HinataHyuga In the screenshot I have an example of a system alert (notification alert on gmail app) which is controlled by iOS and not the app behind. At this point iOS treats the app behind as it is in inactive state (app's applicationstatus will be set to inactive).

Comment: each time `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method call when you got notification.

Comment: Yes @iPatel. But what ideally should be the condition for checking whether user tapped on the notification.

Comment: You want for handle notification when app is active or inactive?

Comment: @HinataHyuga I just want to determine user's tap on the notification.

Comment: I'm having the same problem to. I'll post a solution if I find one.

Comment: I have the same question. Notification handling in ios is a mess...

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: 
(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
         UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
         if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
         { 
              //When your app was active and it got push notification
         }
         else if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) 
         {
              //When your app was in background and it got push notification
         }
}
```

and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called when your app was not running and Launch was clicked in your notification.

As you will display alertview in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you can identify tap in alertview's delegate method i.e. `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`.

Comment: This I understand. I want a reliable check for user's tap on notification even when the user is in the state as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: It is incorrect. This method is called only when app is running. "If the app is not running when a push notification arrives, the method launches the app and provides the appropriate information in the launch options dictionary. The app does not call this method to handle that push notification."

Comment: As it shown in screen shot - this alert is shown by code, it is not a system alert about notification.

Comment: @Shashank I don't understand what state you are talking about?

Comment: @HinataHyuga Notification on gmail app is just an example. It could be an alert like battery down alert/ local notification alert from another app.

Comment: @Shashank If your app is running and you want to do anything, you need to define that here. Otherwise it would not do anything, no alert view will be shown. You need to show your own alertview for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

They fix this issue on ios10, when the add method :

```
userNotificationCenter willPresentNotification.
```

this will only called when the app is in forground/active state, and notification will appear only after the user dismiss the other system alert.

Comment: I think instead what you meant was [`optional func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                          didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
               withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter). <-- This method actually captures the response ie the tap. The `willPresentNotification` is only when app is in **foreground**...and when you're in foreground you just show an alert and process that itself.